# Facebook permission : lost right to publish photo and album

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've created a facebook app a few weeks ago. The app creates an album, and publish some photo inside. All was worked fine.
Since a few days, it doesn't work anymore.
After trying some (hundreds) tests, it seems :
- app login doesn't show photo upload right anymore,
- i can publish photos in main stream, but it doesn't work as well as before : user need to approve photo and i can't create album.

After looking in app parameters on facebook, all seems normal : permission for photo upload are still there...

Does anyone has any idea about this problem ?

Could it be some matters with review from facebook or something like that ?

Thanks for help !

Comment: Review is only needed for Open Graph actions and for an app to appear in the app center. / If the upload feature has been abused/created to many spam complains, it might be that FB has taken the right to create albums and upload photos into them from your app.

Comment: _“After looking in app parameters on facebook, all seems normal : permission for photo upload are still there...”_ – the permissions set there are for login from the app center only. If you’re handling login yourself in your app, you have to ask for permissions via the `scope` parameter.

Comment: Thanks a lot !
I never see that it was needed to send permission via app login from website. Users that i used for test where set up for a while, so i never see that point.
I set up correctly now, so everthing is fine !
Thank you so much for theses comment, you save my sunday, and my app !

Comment: OK, added this as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Review is only needed for Open Graph actions and for an app to appear in the app center.

> After looking in app parameters on facebook, all seems normal : permission for photo upload are still there...

The permissions set there are for login from the app center only. If you’re handling login yourself in your app, you have to ask for permissions via the `scope` parameter.